# What manipulation is allowed when we solve a diophantine equation in $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Suppose we have a Diophantine equation called (A) and we want to show that it has a finite number of solutions in integers, and suppose we made a manipulation on (A) so it becomes (B).

I ask which one of the following manipulations are allowed i.e if we prove that (B) has a finite number of solutions then (A) has a finite number of solutions .

1. multiplying or dividing both sides of (A) by a variable which depends on the equation (ex (A) is $n!+1=m^2$ and we divide it by $2^m$)
2. adding another variable to both side of (A) where this variable doesn't depend on the (A).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot add another variable. Take for example the Diophantine equation $2^n-64=0$. It has finitely many solutions, namely only one solution $n=6$. Adding another variable to both sides changes it to $2^m+2^n-64=2^m$ which has infinitely many solutions $(m,6)$ for all integers $m$.

Conversely however, if the equation $B$ has only finitely many solutions, then cancelling the terms on both sides, also $A$ has only finitely many solutions, because the equations are equivalent.

If we believe in the weak form of Szpiro’s conjecture on elliptic curves, then
$$
n!+1=m^2
$$
has indeed only finitely many integer solutions, which probably are
$$
(n,m)=(4,5),(5,11),(7,71).
$$

Comment: what about my first question and the example there .

Comment: If we prove that  $\frac{(n!+1)}{2^m}=\frac{m^{2}}{2^m}$   has a finite of solution is this enough to prove that $n!+1=m^{2}$ has a finite number of solution ?

Comment: Yes, of course, because the equations are equivalent. You cannot gain anything by dividing both sides. So this "proof method" will, I am sorry to say, not work.

Comment: what do you mean by it is not work? You mean it makes harder

Comment: I mean trying to prove that $n!+1=m^2$ has only finitely many solutions. This requires something like "Szpiro" on elliptic curves or an explicit version of the $abc$-conjecture.

Comment: I am trying to find upper bound for $m$ ( like $m<10^{40}$)I think that I can get good upper bound for the second equation I mean after divide brocard equation by (2^m) is this work to prove that it has a finite number of solution ?

Comment: can put a comment about my last comment